# PowerShell - parametrs of function - casting arraylist?

Tags: xml, powershell

I have Arraylist of objects of my custom class.
How to say function that param will be ArrayList of this class?

```
function CreateArrays{
param(
[System.Collections.ArrayList] $collectionWithItems
)
}
```

I mean something like the following C# declaration:

```
void SomeMethod ( List<myCustomClass> listOfObjects) { }
```

I know I can cast the object within a foreach:

```
foreach($item in [DataBaseItem]$collectionWithItems)
{

}
```

But is there a way to say it in params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `[myCustomClass[]]`:

```
function CreateArrays{
param(
[myCustomClass[]] $collectionWithItems
)
}
```

Comment: when i use this i have following error : At C:\ps\DbConfiguration\dbscript3.ps1:99 char:2
+ [[DataBaseItem[]] $collectionWithItems
+  ~
Missing type name after '['.

Comment: You have two leading `[[`

Comment: ill do that but i have to wait some minutes :P